# How fast can you drink a potion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, potions

Pathfinder material appears to have some conflicts over how long it takes to drink a potion.

From the PRD page on [Potions](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/potions.html):

> Drinking a potion or using an oil is a **standard action.** (...) Using a potion or oil provokes attacks of opportunity.

[Potion Glutton feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/potion-glutton) says, however:

> Benefit(s): You can drink potions, elixirs, or other potables as a swift action without provoking attacks of opportunity.
>
> **Normal: Drinking potions is a move action** that provokes attacks of opportunity.

While [the Accelerated Drinker trait](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/accelerated-drinker) says:

> Benefit: You may drink a potion as a move action instead of a standard action as long as you start your turn with the potion in your hand.

What is correct? Standard or move action?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The feat [Potion Glutton](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/potion-glutton) does, indeed, say in its normal entry that consuming a potion is a move action, and that's been the subject of [some](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder/comments/2fqstq/potion_glutton_raw_this_makes_extracts_a_swift/) [controversy](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/36dk10/is_potion_glutton_overpowered/) as to whether that's [intended](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rm9w?Potion-Glutton-What-does-it-actually-do) or if the feat should be the subject of [errata](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qxs0&page=1?Inner-Sea-Gods-Errata) (and [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r2mg?Swift-action-potion#21) and [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rbdz?Potion-Glutton-and-Extracts#2)).

*I* suspect that the feat's author likely just forgot the actual rule on deadline or accidentally mistyped that normal entry, and that potions still take a standard action to consume. I've found no developer commentary *supporting* a change to the action needed to consume a potion, but I've found none denying such a change, either. Yet changing consuming potions to a move action is important enough—especially at low levels where much of play takes place—that such a change likely would've been announced with more fanfare, instead of being buried in a [setting-specific sourcebook](http://paizo.com/products/btpy94wj?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Gods-Hardcover) in the normal entry of a feat available exclusively to worshipers of a [neutral evil goddess](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Urgathoa).

Comment: As far as I know, the "normal" entry is strictly a reminder, and holds no rules weight whatsoever.

Comment: @fectin That would certainly make adjudicating this errant bit of text easier. Can you cite that?

Comment: Not quickly at least. I thought it was in the feat section under the description of what "normal" means, but that's just copied from the 3.5 SRD. It must have been buried in some errata, but I'm not sure where. Either way, to argue that he normal section of a feat overrides the main text of the core book, you have to show that the normal section is primary. That seems facially false.

Comment: @fectin I don't think Paizo's been nearly as strict (or weird) with its errata policy as Wizards was during *3E*. That is, I'm not altogether certain there **are** *Pathfinder* primary sources (in the *3E* sense, anyway). The linked *Reddit* threads, for instance, make the case for latest printing of a rule overriding earlier printings of a rule, the *context* of that rule being unimportant.

Comment: Especially good considering a spell that takes up 1 minute to cast can be used in a potion yet the spell takes effect immediately after imbibed or applied. So potion consumption being a standard action is good enough.

Comment: There has been no errata yet, but PFS guide says: *Change the text of the potion glutton feat to the following, "Benefit: You can drink potions, elixirs, or other potables (but not extracts) as a move action without provoking an attack of opportunity. **Normal: Drinking potions is a standard action that provokes an attack of opportunity.**"*

Comment: This is a strong indication that the feat will suffer errata when a second print comes.

Answer (score 16):

Though it has been some time since this question was originally answered, its worth noting that the Potion Glutton feat has been clarified in an [official Paizo FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gj#v5748eaic9vbb), quoted below.

> **Potion Glutton: The “Normal” line says that drinking potions is normally a move action. Isn’t it normally a standard action? And if so, the feat text seems to be based on the move action assumption, so what should I do?**
>
> Normally, drinking potions is a standard action, not a move action. To bring it in line with that, change the text of potion glutton to the following: “Benefit: You can drink potions, elixirs, or other potables (but not extracts) as a move action without provoking an attack of opportunity.
> Normal: Drinking potions is a standard action that provokes an attack of opportunity.”

This confirms that the normal action for drinking a potion is a **Standard Action**.